# how to modify values in config file in MFC/C++

Tags: mfc

I'm new to MFC programming. I have to write an application that reads a config file to initilize the application. The config file format is something like:

```
server={192.168.1.254;8080}
device={panasonic}
printer={172.168.10.50;9100}
```

I want to know how to read each key and its value and then write new values back to the config file. If you can give me code example, i would greatly appreciate your kindness

Comment: is the format mandatory ? Can't you use standard .ini files ?

Comment: it's not mine. It's the format which was approved in the old team of my company and my task is to modify value of a specified key. I can't change requirement :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.ini` format, MFC has support for that.

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kayts37a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), look for the ".INI" entries.

Comment: Thank you! It can be the solution I'm looking for. But I have a question. Microsoft mentions that *"Call this member function to write binary data into the specified section of the application's registry or .INI file"*. So how can I guide it to use my file exactly? I don't see the code sample of MSDN talks about this.

Comment: let me try ! Thank you very much

Comment: What if my application use CDialog rather than CWinApp ?